# Using Koa in Nuxt for Shopify Embedded App - css and plugins not imported/injected

Tags: nuxt.js, koa

I am using Koa to serve my app as embedded app for Shopify. I don't have any problems with that since I can install my app using this code:

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch'
import Koa from 'koa'
import { Nuxt, Builder } from 'nuxt'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import shopifyAuth, { verifyRequest } from '@shopify/koa-shopify-auth'

import session from 'koa-session'
import serve from 'koa-static-server'

dotenv.config()
const { SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY, SHOPIFY_API_KEY } = process.env

async function start() {
  const server = new Koa()
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

  // Import and Set Nuxt.js options
  const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
  config.dev = !(server.env === 'production')

  // Instantiate nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  // Build in development
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build().catch((e) => {
      console.error(e)
      process.exit(1)
    })
  } else {
    await nuxt.ready()
  }
  console.log(config)
  console.log(nuxt)

  server.use(session({ secure: true, sameSite: 'none' }, server))
  server.keys = [SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY]

  server.use(
    shopifyAuth({
      apiKey: SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
      secret: SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY,
      scopes: ['read_products', 'write_orders, write_products'],
      afterAuth(ctx) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        const { shop, accessToken } = ctx.session

        console.log('We did it!', accessToken)

        ctx.redirect('/')
      },
    })
  )

  server.use(verifyRequest())

  server.use((ctx) => {
    ctx.status = 200 // koa defaults to 404 when it sees that status is unset

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ctx.res.on('close', resolve)
      ctx.res.on('finish', resolve)
      nuxt.render(ctx.req, ctx.res, (promise) => {
        // nuxt.render passes a rejected promise into callback on error.
        promise.then(resolve).catch(reject)
      })
    })
  })

  server.use(serve({ rootDir: '_nuxt' }))

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
}

start()
```

Now, the thing is my css file and plugins where not imported/injected to my app, here's my nuxt config:

```
import LodashModuleReplacementPlugin from 'lodash-webpack-plugin'
import config from './common.config'
const env = require('dotenv').config()

export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  target: 'static',
  telemetry: process.env.NUXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED,
  env: {
    NUXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED: process.env.NUXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED,
    SHOPIFY_API_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
    SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY,
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    API_ROOT: process.env.API_ROOT,
    API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
  },
  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   */
  head: {
    env: env.parsed,
    title: 'QuickMall',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      {
        name: 'viewport',
        content:
          'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no',
      },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || '',
      },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },
  /*
   ** Global CSS
   */
  css: ['@/assets/scss/app.scss'],
  /*
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
   */
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/persistedState.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/signalr.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vuex-orm-axios.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vuelidate' },
  ],
  /*
   ** Customize the progress-bar color
   */
  loading: { color: '#3B8070' },

  /*
   ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
   */
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/gtm',
  ],
  gtm: {
    // https://github.com/nuxt-community/gtm-module
    // this.$gtm.push({ event: 'myEvent', ...someAttributes })
    // dev: true, // Set to false to disable module in development mode
    // pageTracking: true, // Note: This is disabled by default to prevent double events when using alongside with Google Analytics so take care before enabling this option.
    id: 'GTM-XXXXXX',
  },
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
  ],
  pwa: {
    workbox: {},
    manifest: {
      name: 'QuickMall',
      lang: 'en',
    },
    meta: {},
    icons: {},
  },
  bootstrapVue: {
    componentPlugins: [
      // 'ButtonPlugin',
      // 'CardPlugin',
      // 'CarouselPlugin',
      // 'CollapsePlugin',
      // 'DropdownPlugin',
      // 'FormCheckboxPlugin',
      // 'FormFilePlugin',
      // 'FormGroupPlugin',
      // 'FormRadioPlugin',
      // 'ModalPlugin',
      // 'NavPlugin',
      // 'PaginationPlugin',
      // 'PopoverPlugin',
      // 'ProgressPlugin',
      // 'TablePlugin',
      // 'TabsPlugin',
      // 'ToastPlugin'
      // 'BVToastPlugin',
    ],
    directivePlugins: ['VBScrollspyPlugin', 'VBToggle'],
    css: false,
    bvCSS: true,
  },
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
   */
  axios: config.axios,
  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {
    extractCSS: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    transpile: ['vue-agile'],
    parallel: true,
    // cache: true,
    // hardSource: true,
    // splitChunks: {
    //   layouts: true
    // },
    build: {
      plugins: [new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin()],
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          // Alias for using source of BootstrapVue
          'bootstrap-vue$': 'bootstrap-vue/src/index.js',
        },
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            // Exclude transpiling `node_modules`, except `bootstrap-vue/src`
            exclude: /node_modules\/(?!bootstrap-vue\/src\/)/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['env'],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    babel: {
      plugins: ['lodash'],
      presets: [
        [
          '@nuxt/babel-preset-app',
          {
            corejs: { version: 3 },
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      // Run ESLint on save
      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        })
      }
    },
  },
  nuxtI18n: {
    seo: false,
  },
}
```

when I run the app using `nuxt dev`, the issues is not replicateable. but when using `koa` by running `backpack dev`, the issue can be replicated.

Here's my backpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options, webpack) => {
    config.entry.main = './server/index.js'

    // Add NODE_PATH to webpack.
    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894047/how-to-add-node-path-to-webpack-in-package-json
    config.resolve.modules = ['./server', './server/modules']
    return config
  },
}
```

No error thrown on build, the only thing I notice is that my css and plugins where not imported/injected. Please let me know what I did wrong or how to fix this. I've been comparing my code to the following repos and can't find any differences:

- https://github.com/Hiswe/koa-nuxt-example
- https://github.com/nuxt-community/koa-template

**UPDATE**

So I found out that when running the app using `yarn build` (`nuxt build && backpack build`) and serving it using `yarn start` (`cross-env NODE_ENV=production node build/main.js`), it actually worked fine. I don't know the problem why it is not working using `yarn bp-dev` (`backpack dev`)